# Is there a way to have RPC exposed on Geth such that it can only receive signed transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

Is there a way I can configure my `geth` node RPC to only receive signed transactions?

The goal here is to run a Quorum network where the private state of a node is not visible over RPC. Though the RPC endpoint remains open to receive any inbound signed transactions.

Comment: Parity has functionality to disable some functions, I don't remember if geth has support for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general pattern for things such as this is to disable all remote comms (no --rpc at all) and only use local ipc and wrap this set up with a custom app / api to do what you are trying to do. That said, Quorum does not support sendRawTransaction in private mode at the moment.